# How to disable KiesUsbService from Samsung Galaxy Phone?

Tags: android, debugging, galaxy

I have a Samsung Galaxy S and a problem.  I am trying to debug applications on this phone.  I have no problem, repeat, NO PROBLEM getting the phone into debug mode.

However, after 7 or so minutes, some piece of garbageware called KiesUsbManager starts and disables debug mode and puts the phone into mass storage mode, essentially ending my debug session.

I DO NOT want to install Kies on my mac.  I DO NOT want to transfer media to my phone.  I CAN NOT root the phone to do this.  I WANT to disable this thing and allow my phone to stay in debug mode.

I will happily offer a bounty for an answer that works.

Comment: might have better luck over at http://xda-developers.com, if nothing shows up here. That's the major android hacking center.

Comment: That's where I found all the "metoos" :-(

Comment: about all that comes to mind (and I'm not an android dev) is to root your phone and kill/remove the K.U.M. package, which would hopefully prevent you getting kicked out of debug mode. At least SGS phones are easy to root.

Comment: Mass storage should not be interfering with adb debug, something is seriously broken if it is.

Comment: Kies is garbage, I'm seeing the exact same thing: Samsung Tab development on a Mac, I get about 7 minutes before Kies disables USB debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some info based on some observations.

First, without rooting the phone or whatever I don't think you can access the relevant config files.

Second, I seemed to have a window of about 6 minutes and 41 seconds for how long it will stay connected (maybe there's a protected config file with 400 seconds specified somewhere).  I say that because in several consecutive instances, here are the times for when an unused but usb-debug-connected samsung fascinate was "kicked off" by the Kies service

---

21:42:54.285 last KiesUsbManager Message when it connected

21:49:35.836: KiesUsbManager switches mode and you're done - about 400 seconds

---

21:56:55.430 can connect again

22:03:36.488 it shut off - 401 seconds after I connected

---

22:29:47.367 - came back after supper and it could get back on for usb-debugging

22:36:28:813 - got booted off - about 401 seconds again

---

22:38:09 - could get back on the first time I plugged it back in

22:44:51 - Kies kicked me off - 402 seconds

---

It's not a solution, but says something about the window you have available once you get it to connect... at least on my setup.

Answer (score 0):

Did you figure out how to disable Kies on the phone?

I am seeing this on a Samsung Fascinate as well on an iMac.  I was having connection problems on Win7 before I got this mac, but I didn't pay close attention to logcat at the time.

Based on some other scattered info on the web, I bought a new cable and a powered usb hub, but the problem is still there.  One frustrating aspect of it is that you got to go through the sequence of clicks on the phone to get it back into usb debugging mode...

here's a snippet of my logcat when it happens

3-25 20:26:26.219 D/KiesUsbManager(  114): usb mode = 2

03-25 20:26:26.219 D/KiesUsbManager(  114): UsbMode.cdfs_eject

03-25 20:26:26.219 D/KiesUsbManager(  114): setKiesRun -> true

03-25 20:26:26.219 D/KiesUsbManager(  114): setCDFSEject

03-25 20:26:26.360 D/BatteryService(  114): update start

03-25 20:26:26.383 V/SettingsProvider(  114): secure <- value=0 name=adb_enabled

03-25 20:26:26.387 V/SettingsProvider(  114): property: sys.settings_secure_version=1189

03-25 20:26:26.391 D/VzwLMService(  114): Provider is being enabled: false

03-25 20:26:26.399 V/SettingsProvider(  114): notifying: content://settings/secure/adb_enabled

03-25 20:26:26.399 D/KiesUsbManager(  114): UMS

03-25 20:26:26.399 D/KiesUsbManager(  114): selectUsb -> UMS

maybe there's a config file buried on the phone somewhere that controls how often it runs.  For the moment, I at least understand better what might be going on and can begrudgingly work around it for now.